# error installing thrift: can't find header files for ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, fedora, thrift

I am tying to install `thrift 0.6.1` on my machine ( `linux -  Fedora release 11`). After 'make', I  get following error :

```
/usr/bin/ruby /root/thrift-0.6.1/lib/rb/ext/extconf.rb
can't find header files for ruby.
setup.rb:655:in `command': system("/usr/bin/ruby" "/root/thrift-0.6.1/lib/rb/ext/extconf.rb") failed (RuntimeError)
```

I have `ruby ( 2.0.0-p353)` installed. 
Any suggestions what is causing this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install `ruby-devel`. By the way, Fedora 11 is **really** old.

Comment: Thrift 0.6.1 is also very old. ;-)